# Unreasonable error when double-clicking on Object in Design-time in Delphi

Tags: delphi, events, design-time, delphi-xe

Ok, here is the issue:
Recently I hit an problem that I was not able to use Accelerator Keys ( a.k.a [HotKey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotkey)s ) on Buttons inside GroupBox. Just a minute ago I found out why, but now only problem is that this reason makes me even more puzzled than before, which is that Such *button with accelerator cannot be found on Form*. Effect is that when I double click to affected buttons with double-click while in Design-time, I get error "Property and method  are not compatible".

`MethodName is VKPInputBtnClick`, that is actually declared as function, not as Method in Unit.

What makes me puzzled is that I have not assigned `OnClick` event handler for VKPInputBtn to any Method at all!

How it is possible that I can compile program and have no run-time problems ... but in Design-time double click on button has such annoying issues ....

Any solution? Reinstall of IDE?

Any help much appreciated ...

Comment: So, all this time, it *hasn't* been that the accelerator keys weren't working. In fact, you never had any OnClick handler assigned to the button, so you had no way of telling whether the accelerator was working in the first place. (Did you check whether *clicking* the button worked at run time?)

Comment: Yes, clicking works, but not through OnClick event. It is OnMouseDown -> OnMouseUp ( click validation ) -> function VKPInputBtnClick();. Yes, I had no actual OnClick eventhandler assigned, so I used Forms OnKeyPress to handle these exceptional Accelerator Key functionalities, thatswhy I was vary that OnKeyPress did not fire up ... Seems like I will have to consult Designing as this approach is pretty clumzy ...

Comment: If you're using the mouse events to detect clicks, you're doing it wrong. Use OnClick.

Comment: no, I am using mouse events to split functionality ( with various pre-execution tests ) , allow sequence modularity, reliability for external delphi-based communicable apps, etc. .. but I do not like situation about keyboard handling. After hooks introduction it may cost pretty big rewrites ...;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double-clicking a control that doesn't have its default event property set causes the IDE to assign that property. (It's not just a shortcut for going to the code editor; that's <kbd>F12</kbd>.) The IDE searches the source code for a function with the desired name. If it doesn't find one, then it creates a method in the containing form and assigns it to the component's event property. But if it *does* find something with the right name, it attempts to assign it without creating anything new.

The problem, apparently, is that the thing the IDE finds in your case isn't compatible with the event it appears to go with. Probably a bug — it shouldn't select non-methods — but a rarely encountered one given the low frequency with which humans choose the same name for standalone functions as the IDE chooses for event handlers.

You have several options:

- Rename `VKPInputBtnClick` so it doesn't look like it's the `OnClick` event handler for the `VKPInputBtn` control.
- Make `VKPInputBtnClick` be a method of the form class.
- Manually declare a *new* `VKPInputBtnClick` method in the form class, and maybe the IDE will select it instead of the standalone function.
- Type some other name into the `OnClick` property in the Object Inspector, and *then* double-click it (or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>). The IDE will create a method with that name.

Comment: Hm, thanks, but my current specifications does not allow to use Method as code structure. Only option is function because I need return value(s). I will try renaming though as very last code modification for possible solution.

Comment: You're not allowed to use methods? That's a foolish requirement. Event handlers *must* be methods. If you only meant that the routine currently named `VKPInputBtnClick` cannot be a method, then that's fine; that restriction only eliminates my second suggestion. The others will still work.

Comment: Yes, this and two other controls cannot be methods :( It is pretty ackward, but It is important not to load too much in stack because app contains few very heavy string routines and processing blocks so I have to free data asap. If I would have to use methods ( procedurs ), I would have to init few variables which may become extremly memory-hungry ... and Delphi 2GB would be eaten without salt ...

Comment: Event-handler methods add *nothing* to the stack. And even if they did, if the extra space they occupied really made a difference to your program, then you have much bigger problems. You should never even get into a situation where you're so close to exhausting your stack space. Your stack is 1 MB. It doesn't really affect the 2 GB address-space limit since you can't make your stack any smaller than that anyway. You have a whole megabyte. Feel free to use it to make your life easier, such as by using methods where needed.

Comment: But variables and other common value / data holding elements does add ... :)

Comment: Any variable you need in a method is a variable you'll need in a standalone procedure, too. You're not spending anything additional to use methods. But your event handlers *need* to be methods, so by using standalone procedures, you're actually making it *harder* to accomplish whatever your goal is.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the handler from the .pas file from the declaration and the implementation sections (or copy somewhere if they contain code).  Then try to recreate the handler for the button.  Sometimes the IDE can get out of sync and all that can be done is to reset back to a known state.

If that doesnt work see if you can close the form and reopen, or remove the handler from the .dfm file.

Comment: No, did not work. I am now reinstalling IDE. If no luck, I am making QC @ EDN ...

Answer (score 0):

The components work differently in design and in runtime. Double clicking on a button in desgintime creates and adds an OnClick handler. That explains why the behavior is different.

Hopefully I understand your question correctly. You have a component on your form, and you are not able to assign a correct eventhandler because the automatically created eventhandler is a different type than the expected eventhandler?

In that case, create your own eventhandler and assign it. You can even assign it in the OnCreate of the form. If assignment trough the dfm does not succeed.

Comment: No, I mean that I already have function that does all I need. Problem here is that when I double-click on Component ( button ) on Forms at design-time, IDE should automatically make OnCLick Method ( procedure Button1CLick(Sender: TObject); , for example. Instead of creating such method, it shows this error message. So - now I do not know what to do or where problem could be. My first guess is that IDE finds my function Button1Click(Sender: TObject); and tries to link to it but obviously fails ...

Comment: So, if I assume my guess is correct, this issues is reason why Accelerator Key do not work on this Button1 ...

Answer (score 0):

If this turns out to be a real bug, don't forget to file it with Embarcadero.  You can access the QA app via the tools menu in the IDE or go to the website.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, Question is answered and it is clear that this error message should be a RAD Studio XE bug because IDE in wrong way compares actual and needed properties for Object.

Thank you all very much for input.

EDN QC Case: #89543

---

**Notes:**

This is approach I use to use Accelerator functionality for VKPInputBtnCLick function.
 - Use Message form this code snipp: [Alt key handling algorithm](http://wall.riscom.net/books/delphi/del_faqs/1450.html)
 - Change VK_TAB to VK_LMENU ( left ALT )
 - Once ALT message is captured, set global unique value to variable
 - In FormKeyPress event handler, check if unique global variables value match the one I set before
 - Execute function.

Hope it helps to others willing to do this. Also, some more sleek and clean way to achieve this functionality are welcome, too.

Not setting Question as Answered yet.

Comment: What do the answers you have received so far still lack? What more are you expecting from an answer? You asked how to let the IDE assign a value to your event handler. I gave you four ways. Please note that your question had absolutely nothing to do with how to make accelerator keys work at run time. That's a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

> is actually declared as function, not as Method in Unit.

Method handlers must be procedures, not functions. Hence it doesn't work.

As Toby said a long time ago (but you obviously didn't listen):

> Try deleting the handler from the .pas file ... 
>   Then try to recreate the handler for the button.